# Jenkins job scheduled trigger triggers too often

Tags: scheduled-tasks, jenkins

I have configured a Jenkins job to run every day by using the following scheduling criteria.

H/15 18 * * * (Would last have run at Tuesday, March 19, 2019 6:53:39 PM CET; would next run at Wednesday, March 20, 2019 6:08:39 PM CET.)

However each evening when it runs, it is triggered 4 times.

I have no idea why this is happening, I went through the scheduler and even the pipeline code itself, nothing explains why this happens.

Do you have any idea why my job is triggered 4 times each evening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Meaning of H/5 in cron Jenkins on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302607/meaning-of-h-5-in-cron-jenkins):

> H/5 in the first field means Every five minutes starting at some time between 0 and 4 minutes past the hour
>
> So H/5 3,21 * * 1-5
>
> is Every five minutes between 03:00 and 03:59 and then between 21:00 and 21:59 on Mon -> Fri but starting at some 'random' time between 03:00 and 03:04 and then the same number of minutes after 21:00

You're telling him to run your job every 15 minutes starting at 18:00. 60 minutes/15 = 4.

Comment: I have altered it to be H 7 * * * causing it to run daily (only once) around 19:00 hours.
Thank you for your explanation, now I understand the syntax better.

Comment: also, just as an FYI, the Jenkins syntax is almost identical to the [Unix crontab syntax](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).  That style of syntax is pretty common for job schedulers.